# Unable to Get object property value directly in Powershell 2.0

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I tried a script I had built on Powershell 3 and greater versions. Having Issue with compatibility in Powershell 2.0

```
$JsonConfig = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\Utilities\conf\cmsAgent.conf
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions") | out-null
$javaSerializer = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$deserialziedJson = New-Object -type PSObject -Property $javaSerializer.DeserializeObject($JsonConfig)


$API = $deserialziedJson.API
$APIURL = "https://$($API.Server)/$($API.EndPoint)"

$Message = $null
Write-host "test"
Write-host $($API)
Write-host $API.Server
Write-host $API.Port
```

I am getting the following output:

```
test
[Server, ghtk.net.com] [Port, 443] [EndPoint, xyzhtc]
    
0
```

Hence $API.Port and $API.Server seem to be returning a null value. I believe this is since direct referencing to PSObject was not introduced in PS Version 2.

Please advise on a workaround which can be compatible with higher versions too.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test it on v2 at the moment, but what should *definitely* always work is simply indexing directly with the keys. (Attention: case-sensitive!)

```bsh
$deserializedJson = $javaSerializer.DeserializeObject($JsonConfig)
$api = $deserializedJson["API"]
$server = $api["Server"]
$port = $api["Port"]
$APIURL = "https://${server}:$port/$($API["EndPoint"])"
```